# change name of shared library using libtool

Tags: linux, compilation, libtool

I am playing around with libtool in linux, is there a way to change the name of the produced shared library? I tried using the AC_INIT macro in configure.ac but there is no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an easy way to do this with `libtool` AFAIK.  If you need to rename `libfoo.la` to `libbar.la`, the easiest way is to rename it in the makefile.